# Laravel adding data to pivot table while inserting new record

Tags: laravel, eloquent, pivot-table

I have three tables,

```
roles(id, name);
users(id, email, password);
user_role(id, user_id, role_id);
```

In this scenario, I have users table is associated to roles table with many to many relation.

I have two eloquent model as

```
Role
+users(){
    belongsToMany('User')
}

User
+roles(){
    belongsToMany('Role')
}
```

Now, the question is when I want to add a new user along with ids of roles that I would like to assign to users. How can I insert values to pivot table with Laravel best practices?

My existing code is:-

```
$roles = Input::get('roles'); // arrays of role ids

$user = new User();
$user->username = Input::get('username');
$user->password = Hash::make(Input::get('password'));
$user->save();
```

What to do next???

Comment: Just like here: http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#inserting-related-models

Answer (score 42, accepted):

It's really all [described in the documentation](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#inserting-related-models).

Anyway, here's how you do it:

```
$user = new User();
$user->username = Input::get('username');
$user->password = Hash::make(Input::get('password'));
$user->save();
$user->roles()->attach($roles);
```

The important part is that you have to save the user before attaching (using [`attach()`](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#attaching-detaching)) the roles because otherwise the user doesn't have an id yet to be used in the pivot table.

Comment: I tried it, but it is returning an error, 
Call to undefined method Illuminate\\Database\\Eloquent\\Collection::attach()

Comment: Just to clarify, the parentheses matter! ```$user->roles()``` NOT ```$user->roles```

Comment: @lukasgeiter it's not that clear. How are we to know the `attach()` needs to be done after the record has been saved?

Comment: @surfer190 Well that's how all eloquent relations work. First you save one side, and then associate the other. But I agree that this might not be very clear from the documentation.

Comment: The same goes in laravel 5.4 also?

Comment: Yes @siddiq same goes for 5.4 . Need to insert one record before trying to associate it with another since the association uses the primary key from the parent to insert into the child so if there hasn't been an insertion, then there will be no id.

Comment: Another clarification, this only works with `belongsToMany` relationship and not `hasMany`

Comment: I am confused, what is the type of  $roles variable is it an object or array please clarify that I also read the documentation but is a bit complicated for me?

Comment: Knowing what to look for in the documentation is half the battle for new people.

Answer (score 0):

If there are timestamps like `created_at` and `updated_at` on the pivot table, you can pass those as another parameter to the [`attach`](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships#updating-many-to-many-relationships) method like below.

```
<?php

use Carbon\Carbon;

// Assuming $roles is an array, say like having values as [1,2,80,200] etc.

$user->save();
$user->roles()->attach($roles, array(
   'created_at' => Carbon::now(), // or date("Y-m-d H:i:s")
   'updated_at' => Carbon::now()
));
```